# Oozie > EL function > is it possible to add variable in EL functions

Tags: oozie

In a `Oozie` workflow, we can add variable `${VAR}` and define the value of this `${var}` in the properties file. But Is it possible to use such `${var}` as input of `EL function`?

For instance, `equalsIgnoreCases(${var})`. It seems not, but if so I still feel `Oozie` is almost terrible. It is like a tool from over 20 years ago. So is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I actually have tried equalsIgnoreCases(${var}), it really really really did not work. You can make a simple test for that. The only way to get the value of var is by el function wf:conf('var'). In this sense I still feel oozie is really terrible

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still required but the expression you need to use is:

```
${equalsIgnoreCases(var)}
```

Thanks.